# Why does my app work when I comment and un-comment it

Tags: reactjs, axios, jsx, array.prototype.map

```
import React from 'react'
import CoinItem from './CoinItem'

const Coins = (props) => {

  return (
      <div className='container'>
        <div>
          <div className='heading'>
    <p>#</p>
    <p className='coin-name'>Coins</p>
    <p>Price</p>
    <p>24h</p>
    <p className = 'hide-mobile'>Volume</p>
    <p className = 'hide-mobile'>Market Cap</p>
         </div>
         {props.coins.map(coins => {
            return (
                <CoinItem coins={coins} key={coins.id} />
            )
         })}
    </div>
</div>
  )
}

export default Coins
```

With this code, my app won't render and I get the error, "Uncaught TypeError: props.coins.map is not a function." However, it directs me to the line where I create a div with the class name of the heading.

**However, when I comment out:**

```
{props.coins.map(coins => {
        return (
            <CoinItem coins={coins} key={coins.id} />
        )
     })}
```

**and uncomment it again, my app renders perfectly with the API working, but once again, when I refresh, the app de-renders.**

How do I fix this?

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cloud-pcfne0?file=/src/components/Coins.js:409-512

Comment: How is ```Coins``` component used ?

Comment: Please provide a working sandbox link of the code so, the whole code can be seen. It seems to work on un-comment after comment because the virtual dom updates itself without HTML reload

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cloud-pcfne0?file=/src/components/CoinItem.js --------(Try commenting and uncommenting lines 17-21 in Coin.js. It should work until you refresh.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can do is:

1. Ensure that the "coins" prop exists.
2. If it exists, make sure it is an Array and not an Object. You cannot use .map() on an Object. it is an Array method.
3. To avoid the code running a .map() when coins is null/undefined, add a ? after props.coins so that the .map() runs only if coins is defined.

   `{props.coins?.map(coin => { /*YOUR CODE HERE*/ })`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I put the props.coin? and it still doesn't work. I just don't understand why i have to comment and uncomment my code for it to work.

Comment: Did you make sure that coins is an array? Maybe try be logging coins into your console and check it out.

Comment: How can I achieve the same results as .map() with an object?